# Confused why columns won't change to type numeric when applying pd.to_numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where the first column contains names as strings which I need to retain and the rest of the columns contain a mix of numbers and strings. I'm only interested in the numbers so I want to convert these columns to numeric and force the string values to NaN which I can do using errors="coerce"

But for some reason when I use pd.to_numeric on these columns and coerce errors they still come back as type object

```
print(df.info())
df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')) 
print(df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 867 entries, 0 to 866
Data columns (total 15 columns):
Sample Name    867 non-null object
PFBS           196 non-null object
PFHxS          829 non-null object
PFOS           827 non-null object
PFHpA          301 non-null object
PFOA           711 non-null object
PFNA           744 non-null object
PFDA           625 non-null object
PFUnDA         378 non-null object
PFDoDA         236 non-null object
PFOSA          118 non-null object
N-EtFOSAA      638 non-null object
N-MeFOSAA      541 non-null object
PFPeA          437 non-null object
PFHxA          217 non-null object
dtypes: object(15)
memory usage: 101.7+ KB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 867 entries, 0 to 866
Data columns (total 15 columns):
Sample Name    867 non-null object
PFBS           196 non-null object
PFHxS          829 non-null object
PFOS           827 non-null object
PFHpA          301 non-null object
PFOA           711 non-null object
PFNA           744 non-null object
PFDA           625 non-null object
PFUnDA         378 non-null object
PFDoDA         236 non-null object
PFOSA          118 non-null object
N-EtFOSAA      638 non-null object
N-MeFOSAA      541 non-null object
PFPeA          437 non-null object
PFHxA          217 non-null object
dtypes: object(15)
memory usage: 101.7+ KB
None
```

to get this to work I had to do

```
cols=df.columns.drop("Sample Name")
df[cols]=df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```

why does this work but using apply on a slice of a dataframe doesn't? Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to remove "Sample Name" column to use this:

```
df.drop("Sample Name", axis = 1)
```

check also Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas-dataframe-drop)

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get cells with strings to NaN in a column:

```
df.loc[df['column'].str.contains('')==True, 'column'] = np.nan
```